# 400 Bad request with Hibernate @Valid

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, tomcat, hibernate-validator

I have a strange behaviour when I validate my form.

As soon as I add the Hibernate @Valid annotation, Tomcat consided my request as "bad" if the posted data are not valid. If the data are valid, no worries.

I use:

- Tomcat 7.0.52
- Javax Validation api 1.1.0.Final
- Hibernate Validator 5.1.0.Final
- Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE

At the moment, I do a really simple validation:

```
public class RemoveCacheElementForm {

    @NotBlank(message = "Please select a cache name.")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please select a cache entry key.")
    private String key;
```

The Spring controller:

```
/**
 * Handler to remove one cached elements from the specified cache.
 * 
 * @return the view.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = CACHE_REMOVE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String removeCachedElement(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute(FORM_NAME) RemoveCacheElementForm form) {
    model.addAttribute("removeElementResult", CacheUtils.removeCachedElement(form.getName(), form.getKey()));
    initializeModel(model);
    return CACHE_ADMIN_PAGE;
}
```

When I remove @Valid annotation, no worries too.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks a lot for your help! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing your code to

```
@RequestMapping(value = CACHE_REMOVE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String removeCachedElement(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute(FORM_NAME) RemoveCacheElementForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    model.addAttribute("removeElementResult", CacheUtils.removeCachedElement(form.getName(), form.getKey()));
    initializeModel(model);
    return CACHE_ADMIN_PAGE;
}
```

Comment: Great!! It works!! Just because a missing argument (and finally an important argument... ;-) ).

A big thank you geoand! :-)

Comment: @Didasko No problem! If it's not too much trouble please accept the answer (or some other one that helps you with your problem) as correct so users in the future will know that it's correct without reading the comments.

Comment: @Didasko Ok! Great :)

Comment: @Didasko how `BindingResult` has helped to prevent 400 bad request error?

Comment: @Vish - Hi! `BindingResult` helped me to prevent bad request simply because when Spring validates with the JSR-303 provider (anytime `@Valid` is encountered), Spring needs something to expose the potential errors. This "something" for Spring is a `BindingResult` object. And this `BindingResult` object was missing in the arguments of my method. => [Spring Validation Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-jsr303)