# 400 Bad request when validation Model Attribute with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am writing a simple controller that accepts request on user sign-up I want to validate the Model Attribute but I receive 400 bad request. 
I've checked [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202788/400-bad-request-with-hibernate-valid) and is pretty much the problem I have but the solutions does not work for me.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/sign-up", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public ModelAndView addUser(ModelMap model,@Valid @ModelAttribute
    UserRegistrationInfo userRegistrationInfo,
                                HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
                                HttpSession httpSession,
                                BindingResult result) { ..... }
```

***EDIT***

Spring Version: 4.0.6.RELEASE

I've read SpringMVC architecture and set a break points at `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`class, `doResolveException` method and found that a BindException exception is thrown.However, I did not know why BindingResult is not filled and method execution is not called to let me determine what behavior I want ? the execution ends up at return `handleBindException((BindException) ex, request, response, handler);` which is

```
protected ModelAndView handleBindException(BindException ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException { response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST); return new ModelAndView(); }
```

Comment: please attach stack-trace or log !!

Comment: Well, this is that I tried to look at the first time but nothing suspicious so far

Comment: No logs so far I could not find anything ... it returns gracefully without any logs

Comment: What does UserRegistrationInfo look like? Does it have a no-arg constructor?

Comment: Yes, It actually has one setters and getters

Comment: I've read SpringMVC architecture and set a bread points at DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver-> class, doResolveException -> method and found that a  BindException exception is thrown however I don't know what BindingResult is not filled and method execution is not called to let me determine what behavior I want ? the execution ends up at  return handleBindException((BindException) ex, request, response, handler); which is :

Comment: protected ModelAndView handleBindException(BindException ex, HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException {
  response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
  return new ModelAndView();
 }

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you've rightly figure out, you're getting a bad request on account of the binding errors. All the info that you need are in fact contained in the `BindingResult` object but in order to use it properly you should set your `BindingResult` to immediately follow your `ModelAttribute` e.g.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/sign-up", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public ModelAndView addUser(ModelMap model,@Valid @ModelAttribute
    UserRegistrationInfo userRegistrationInfo, BindingResult result
                                HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
                                HttpSession httpSession,
                                ) { ..... }
```

While ordering of arguments generally doesn't matter, `BindingResult` parameter is an exception, as the method can contain several `ModelAttribute` parameters, each having its own dedicated instance of `BindingResult`. In this case the association is established by having the `BindingResult` parameter immediately follow the `ModelAttribute` it applies to.

When you reorder your parameters you will no longer get the `400` error, rather the request will enter the controller, and the logs will show the exact binding problem, or you simply check if `result.hasErrors()` and iterate through field errors by calling `result.getAllErrors()`. Then it should be simple enough to resolve your binding issue and the consequent bad request.

Check the section od the doc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods